# Posting a new answer based on "link only answers"

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers

Plenty of link only answers get posted every day. The worst offenders are usually along the lines of:

> Try something like this: www.example.com

These answers are flagged "NAA" and get deleted most of the time.

*Occasionally* the original authors update the answer with a short summary, but in the large majority of cases any helpful information contained in the linked resource gets hidden in a deleted answer.

Is it acceptable to post a new answer summarizing the relevant portions from the off-site resource?

Comment: That is unfortunate, in the olden days such info got preserved by converting the answer to a comment.  Not sure why this practice fell out of favor.  But sure, by all means, let it rip.

Comment: Only moderators can convert to comment. There are some situations where posts handled in the LQPRQ will be shown to modertors at which point they can choose to resurrect the answer in the form of a comment.

Comment: I tend to repost the link as a comment under the question, and _then_ flag as NAA, so that the Review Queue can remove without having to do extra work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. As a matter of fact, more generally speaking, you can post the same solution as an existing answer, as long as you believe your explanation is better. Many questions have multiple answers that are the same solution using the same approach, but are explained differently. I would think this situation is the same. His explanation is the link itself, not the content of the link. As always, do make sure you link and give credit to any links you use to create your answers.

Comment: So you are advocating taking someone's answer, with their existing code, and just explaining it differently? That will not go over well.

Comment: @TravisJ The answer advocated providing an answer using the same approach to solving the problem; it didn't specify whether it was independently arrived at or a derived work of another's.  That said, it is entirely appropriate to post an answer that is a derived work of another person's, possibly by focusing on improving the explanation rather than the code.  Naturally you'd need to cite the work properly, indicating what works are yours and what aren't, and so on.  Whether readers feel the derived work is more or less valuable than the original will of course vary greatly on the specifics.

Comment: @TravisJ If someone posts "do `.join(',')`" as an answer, I think others are allowed to use that same code or same approach in their answers. If you're taking a large amount of code from another answer, you'll probably want to mention that you're building off an existing answer and credit that person the same you would if you were building your answer off of a linked resource, such as the question here.

Comment: @Goose @Servy - The problem is that there have been problems in the past where users are not providing the proper citation of the work. Using derived work is fine, and often if `.join(',')` is all there was more than likely both answers came up with that solution independently, but advocating users to "post a new answer summarizing the relevant portions" from "existing answer(s)" leads to a lot of problems down the road.

Comment: @TravisJ True. My answer is really more intended for the situation in OP. If someone posts a link only answer, I think it's fine to reference the same link in your answer, and provide a better in answer explanation.

Comment: @Goose - I agree it is fine to reference the same link in your answer and provide a better explanation.

Comment: @TravisJ Yeah this question is really specifically about answers that only provided a link and no explanation at all. Where there is nothing to cite but the link itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it acceptable to post a new answer summarizing the relevant portions from the off-site resource?

Yes. But there are nuances.

You are asking about a choice: to post new answer or to do something else.

Usually (most of times?) just post a new answer with relevant portion of information and the link. For a sake of friendship, give some credits to that other link-only answer, by mentioning what you are improving it.

Is the answer old? And original answerer didn't bother to post details, it's his problems, right?

If you had the OP problem and found the answer and follow the link and it helped you: how hard is for you would be to find that link alone and how much time you waste there:

- Hard/impossible to find? Then this answer is valuable, right? Then maybe editing it and adding some details to protect it from link-rotting is a good pay-off (as well as upvoting) for the help you've got.
- Easy or super-easy/obvious (msdn) to find? Then this answer worth nothing and posting your not-link-only answer is a good idea.
- You wasted hours to read linked info and to produce working solution? Then just post working solution to help further readers and to save their time; links to whatever are totally optional.

Comment: The link-only answer *isn't an answer* according to the standards of SO.  So credit to the author is nice, but the answer itself doesn't need to be cited (and should in fact be deleted).

Comment: @BenVoigt, if the link is really hard to find, then using it in own answer and deleting original answer is like stealing, right?

Comment: You give credit to the person who posted the link as if they had done the right thing and put it in a comment.  It makes no sense to cite an answer which doesn't meet the minimum quality standard for answers.

Comment: Ah, if you thought I meant "person who wrote the off-site resource" by *author*, I can see why you would disagree.

Answer (score -11):

Ideally, you would just edit the existing post to include the relative information from the link.

This is in most ways charity work, as all the credit from the edit improvement goes to the user who originally just copy pasted the link and left it as such. I understand not wanting to do that, but really that *should* be the way it goes.

I don't think posting a new answer with the relevant content and a link to the source is a good idea, although it is similarly hard to argue against it happening. Copying a link cannot be plagiarism - unless it has some sort of custom code in a query string, or some other extremely rare case, but that isn't what I meant - so, if that is the route you would like to go I don't think there is any good reason not to. Firmly of the stance of "meh" in that situation.

In the modern web, sites include several keys to providing previews. While these previews may not say much for some places, they work semi well for others. It would make sense, and be relatively easy, for Stack Overflow to implement one boxing for links in answers. The meta data exists on many sites, and that is why you commonly see previews now in smart phone link only text messages.

Comment: I thought about editing the existing answer but thought it didn't really make sense. At that point I am writing my own thoughts and ideas based on a resource someone else linked. The original poster might have a different view on how the resource should be summarized or feel that I summarized it incorrectly and in either case my contribution could be destroyed without my knowledge down the line. If I am putting my own ideas and voice into an edit to an answer, wouldn't it make more sense to post a new answer?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic - There is a precedence for editing the content into the answer (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/334916/revisions?page=5). That is a long read, so make sure to take in the context of why I linked to the 5th page of revisions as well as the general post. That said, if you are adding in additional content which is yours and is not present with the link, then it absolutely makes sense for you to post your own answer.

Comment: Note that for a user without editing privileges, it might be difficult to get an answer-saving edit through the suggested edit queue. Reviewers might think that adding an entire section of text changes the author's intentions.

Comment: @AndrewMyers - In that scenario it may make sense to convert the link into a separate answer. That said, reviewers should not be declining valid edits.

Comment: Make sure that if you include relevant information from the link, that you actually have the rights to do so. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange

Comment: @Chris - That is always good advice, even without the link only expansions. Being cautious about pasting code from other sources is something answerers should hopefully already be aware of, and if not that is a good place to at least review.

Comment: "really that should be the way it goes." It really should _not_. I don't expect every answerer to have read [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/334566), but I expect them to understand that questions and answers on Stack Exchange sites must not rely on external links to be meaningful. If you fix a link-only answer by adding the offsite material (with attribution to the offsite author) and the answer receives subsequent upvotes, the link-only person shouldn't receive that rep. That's simply rewarding bad behaviour.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic "*At that point I am writing my own thoughts and ideas based on a resource someone else linked.*" - sure, if you are writing your *own* answer that is just *based on* the linked resource, then by all means you should make your own post. I would have understood the "*summarizing the relevant portions from the off-site resource*" to be just quoting some relevant excerpts from the linked page - that I would do as an edit.